# solr date format

Tags: solr

I'm a little confused over the format of date that solr expects, I know it has to be of the format:

2012-05-10T20:11:01.057Z

An index that I am looking at his added a trailing z to the end of this such that it is of the form:

2012-05-10T20:09:50.567ZZ

This doesn't actually throw an error on my version of solr which is 3.5 (but it does on older versions). Is 3.5 more tolerant of poorly formed date formats? I know that the DateField class as defined by apache needs a single 'Z' at the end to denote the UTC time. I guess I'm looking for an indication as to why this would be causing problems in earlier versions than 3.5?

Comment: Just to clarify, the second dateformat I have been given has two characters 'Z' at the end, rather than one that is expected

Answer (score 0):

I ran this same index with an older version of SOLR and it appears that version 3.5 corrects for the additional 'Z' at the end whereas older versions do not.